# How to connect with an IPv6 address using SSH.NET library in C#

Tags: c#, ssh, ipv6, ssh.net

I want to connect via SSH to a remote GNU+Linux machine and execute a command, but with an IPv6 address. With an IPv4 address it works perfectly fine.

I am running on Ubuntu 15.04 and use MonoDevelop (Mono 4.0)

Here is my sample code using Renci SSH.NET library:

```
SshClient sshClient = new SshClient (ipV6Address, user, pass);
sshClient.Connect ();
SshCommand sshCmd = sshClient.RunCommand (command);
sshClient.Disconnect ();
```

I also tried to use Tamirs SshSharp and Terminal Control.

Adding `[ ]` to the IPv6 address didn't work either.

I get following exception:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Invalid arguments
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket+SocketAsyncResult.CheckIfThrowDelayedException () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0  
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect (IAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Renci.SshNet.Session.SocketConnect (System.String host, Int32 port) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Renci.SshNet.Session.Connect () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Renci.SshNet.BaseClient.Connect () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at main program...
```

Maybe someone could provide me a code example (in C#) or tell me a library that clearly supports IPv6 addresses. The library should be free (preferably with Apache license) and usable for commercial use.

Greetings Wima

**EDIT:**

After coming to the conclusion that my `ipAddress` lacks the network interface I changed my `ipAddress` to `"fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx%2"` (yes 2 is the right one, I tested with ping6).

This seems to work a bit "more", because the exception changed into:

```
System.ArgumentException: host
at Renci.SshNet.ConnectionInfo..ctor (System.String host, Int32 port, System.String username, ProxyTypes proxyType, System.String proxyHost, Int32 proxyPort, System.String proxyUsername, System.String proxyPassword, Renci.SshNet.AuthenticationMethod[] authenticationMethods) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Renci.SshNet.PasswordConnectionInfo..ctor (System.String host, Int32 port, System.String username, System.Byte[] password, ProxyTypes proxyType, System.String proxyHost, Int32 proxyPort, System.String proxyUsername, System.String proxyPassword) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Renci.SshNet.PasswordConnectionInfo..ctor (System.String host, Int32 port, System.String username, System.String password) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Renci.SshNet.SshClient..ctor (System.String host, Int32 port, System.String username, System.String password) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Renci.SshNet.SshClient..ctor (System.String host, System.String username, System.String password) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at main program...
```

**SOLVED**

Using the pre-release package of SSH.NET solved my problem!

Thanks to @MartinPrikryl and others ;)

Comment: What error do you get when you try to use and IPv6 address? Forgive me for my cynicism but are you sure you network supports ipv6?

Comment: Did you try to connect to the server using IPv6 using a GUI SSH client first? Like from PuTTY?

Comment: Yes my network supports IPv6.
Connecting via ssh from shell is functioning.
Sry i forgot adding the error message ^^, but i added it now.

Comment: Did a quick search this looks relevant https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Comment: Thank you @pcwizz
So your link states that it is probably incompatible with ipv6, very interesting.
I would upvote your comment, if i had enough reputation. But i'll try to remember to do it :)

Comment: What is the actual value of `ipV6Address` that you try to use?

Comment: kind of:  
ipV6Address = IPAddress.Parse("ipv6 string");

Comment: And what is the `ipv6 string`?

Comment: it's "fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx", where x is a hex value

Comment: Do not even try the SharpSsh. It's a dead project. Not updated for over 8 years!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you connect to a link local adress (FE80::) then you need to specify the interface name with a % eg FE80::%eth0

Because you can have multiple link local addresses and you need to tell your OS which interface to use. With unicast addresses the OS knows due to the routing table what interface to use.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a bit further. I use now "fe80::.......%2", which seems to work better, because the exception changed into "System.ArgumentException: host" . I will describe the full error message in my main post

Comment: @Wima It actually works even worse as the IP does not even get last a validation in SSH.NET `ConnectionInfo`. Anyway, I'm getting no exception when passing `fe80::2e0:dff:fe9d:307%2` to `host` argument of `SshClient` constructor. What version of SSH.NET are you using? There was indeed some kind of regex validation of IP address in past versions of SSH.NET that would not accept the interface name. But it is not there anymore (the latest version 2014.4.6-beta2).

Comment: I use Version 2013.4.7 of SSH.NET

Comment: Well, you need to upgrade!

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thank you very much kind sir, that solved my problem. I will upvote you, when i get enough reputation!

Comment: @Wima You are welcome. There's nothing to upvote, this is not my answer.